# Android AlertDialog (promptview) hide Keyboard

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Because it's an promptView and not an Activity, I can't go to Manifest to hide the Keyboard.
I searched around the google and I found similiar topics, but I can't figure out how to put this working.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt_firstime, null);

final EditText nameInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.prompt_name);
final EditText emailInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.prompt_email);

InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(nameInput.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(emailInput.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Menu.this).create();  
alertDialog.setTitle("Title");  
alertDialog.setView(promptsView);
// etc
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It may fix your problem.

```
your_activityName.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, just pass your activity context while calling

```
public static void hidekeypad(Activity activity)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Comment: How should I call that function? `hidekeypad(this)`, if so, I got errors. `10-25 09:08:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(2777): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testing/com.example.testing.Menu_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`
I called the function on the @oncreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.. It worked in my case:)

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(your_edit_text.getWindowToken(), 0);
```